# I cannot connect to Redis image from a Node image within Docker

Tags: docker, redis

First all was working great with default configuration until I hit one memory limit, then I needed to add a [Redis configuration file](https://redis.io/docs/manual/config/) (latest, 7.0). In this file bind is set to `127.0.0.1` with default port, so I tried that. I also changed that to `bind 0.0.0.0` but I got the same error.

Now in for my environment variables I'm putting: ~redis//redis:6379~ or `redis:6379` so here is my configuration (docker-compose.yml):

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  classified-ads:
    container_name: classified-ads
    depends_on:
      - redis-service
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    build:
      context: ./
    # restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REDIS_URI=redis:6379
      - INSIDE_DOCKER=wahoo
  # our custom image 
  redis:
      container_name: redis-service
      build:
        context: ./docker/redis/
      privileged: true
      command: sh -c "./init.sh"
      ports:
        - '6379:6379'
      volumes: 
        - ./host-db/redis-data:/data/redis:rw
```

The error I'm getting is bloated and is from my client which is `ioredis` but it is clearly a connection error. (ioredis wrapped with Fastify/redis, so it is a failed promise that is very verbose but not clearly indicative, but it's 100% a connection error).

I checked Redis logs piped to Docker and it is running fine.

Edit: `ping redis//redis:6379` does not work from my app image while `ping redis:6379` works so I changed that.

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/i-cannot-connect-to-redis-image-from-a-node-image-within-docker/126700

Answer (score 0):

I found the sollution. While the default redis:alpine image use configuration with `protection_mode yes` I was using a new configuration with `protection_mode no`. I also removed the `bind 'address'` all together.

And reconnected normally from other services with `redis:port` as usual.
all thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541475/1951298